# Next.js Image component don't load in deploy

Tags: next.js

In my project I'm working with next.js and for images I'm using `<Image/>` component and on localhost everything is fine but when I deploy project on a server it doesn't load images and images URL come from the same server I deploy the project on it.

here is next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ["example.com", "http://example.com"],
  },
};
```

and this is how I pass the image url

```
<Image src={`http://example.com/${img}`} alt="something" />
```

Comment: How did you pass the src of image to <Image /> component?

Comment: @HuanLe took it from the api and pass it to src

Comment: Can you show the code how you are plugging the src into <image> and what server is used for deployment?

Comment: @LakshyaSharma I edit the question and wrote how I pass it to Image and I use nginx, is it possible that the problem is from backend and not from frontend?

Comment: @emhossein Can you try using just img tag, if that is not working then the issues will be for sure from backend connectivity, or maybe url not working from where you are deploying. And can you also please check if the url is http and not https.

Comment: @LakshyaSharma with <img/> everything works fine but I want to use Image and also I better mention this when I locally use npm run build and then npm start images load but on server it won't load

Comment: @emhossein The (next/image) component relies on the Next Server running. when you use next run build and next run start it starts the next server as well. Can you share how you are deploying the application using nginx and confirm if next server is running correctly.
I think as you are using nginx, you should be using custom loader like imgix 
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader-configuration